# Self hosted Web.Api - accessing HttpRequestMessage or dependency resolver in attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a Web.Api application currently running under IIS which is being converted to a self hosted application using Owin.

I have a requirement to access the dependency resolver from within an attribute so I can access an instance of a service. (the app is using Unity for DI).

As I can't see a way to inject this service into the attribute (if there is then I'd love to hear about it), I currently grab the resolver from the `HttpRequestMessage` via `HttpContext.Current`:-

```
HttpRequestMessage request = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;

var service = request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IService)) as IService;
```

This works fine with the app running under IIS, but under Owin `HttpContext` is not present.

I came across [OwinRequestScopeContext](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext) which I configure in my app startup:-

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.UseRequestScopeContext();

    \\...
```

And assign a reference to the request object from within a `DelegatingHandler`

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Items["HttpRequestMessage"] = request;

    \\...
```

But when I access `OwinRequestScopeContext` in my attribute, `OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Items` is empty.

I seem to be having the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194836/passing-logical-call-context-from-owin-pipeline-to-webapi-controller) but the supplied answer doesn't seem to address my issue.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with `OwinRequestScopeContext` and/or what is the simplest way I can gain access to the dependency resolver or HttpRequestMessage from within my attribute?